# core.js:6237 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'area' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

HTML: Here is my form. When I click the submit button I have got this error. I don't know Where I am getting wrong. Can you please help?

```
<h3 class="page-header">Operator Form</h3>
<div class="outer-container">
   <form class="form-section" [formGroup]="operatorForm" (ngSubmit)="save()">
        <!-- <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Drone Type" formControlName="drone_type" required>
        </mat-form-field> -->
        <mat-form-field>    
            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Police Station" formControlName="police" readonly>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Area" formControlName="area" required>
        </mat-form-field>
        <!-- <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Date and Time</mat-label>
             <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="date" readonly/>
             <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
             <mat-datepicker #picker disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>    
         </mat-form-field> -->
         <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="picker" placeholder="Date and Time" 
                formControlName="date"
                [disabled]="disabled">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <ngx-mat-datetime-picker #picker [showSpinners]="showSpinners" [showSeconds]="showSeconds"
               [stepHour]="stepHour" [stepMinute]="stepMinute" [stepSecond]="stepSecond"
               [touchUi]="touchUi" [color]="color" [enableMeridian]="enableMeridian">
            </ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
         </mat-form-field>

        <div style="text-align: right">
            <button mat-raised-button type="submit" [disabled]="operatorForm.invalid" >Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="spinner" [style.display]="showSpinner ? 'flex' : 'none'">
    <mat-spinner [diameter]="30" ></mat-spinner>
</div>
```

component.ts:(Here is my form.. when i click submit button I have got this error. dont know Where i am getting wrong.. can you please help? )

```
payload: any;
ngOnInit(){
   this.operatorForm = new FormGroup({  
     'police': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
     'area': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
     'date': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),  
    })
}
save() {
   this.payload.area = this.operatorForm.get('area').value
   this.payload.flightDateTimeStr = this.operatorForm.get('date').value,
   console.log(this.payload)
}
```

Comment: console log this.payload in save method. I believe its undefined.

Comment: try the solution i gave below :-

Comment: Yes payload is getting undefined.

Comment: try the solution given below.

Comment: please mark it as answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

```
payload ={};
  ngOnInit(){
     this.operatorForm = new FormGroup({

      'police': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'area': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'date': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),

     })
   }
  save(){
        this.payload["area"] = this.operatorForm.get('area').value
        this.payload["flightDateTimeStr"] = this.operatorForm.get('date').value,
      console.log(this.payload)
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  not dynamically inject keys like that in save method to the payload. 
Follow this code.

```
payload: any;

save(){
   this.payload = {
      area: this.operatorForm.get('area').value,
      flightDateTimeStr: this.operatorForm.get('date').value,
   } 
}
```

If you want to cast the object then exports interface and typecast the properties of the object like this.

```
export interface PayLoad {
   area: any;
   flightDateTimeStr: any;
}

payload: PayLoad;
```